# Formidable node.js error

Tags: node.js, debugging

I am new to node js and encounter this error when running

```
npm install
```

Error: formidable@1.0.17: Old versions of Formidable are not compatible with the current Node.js; Upgrade to 1.2.0 or later

How do I upgrade?

Comment: Did you try `npm update formidable`?  Or, if formidable is only being used as a dependency of some other module, you may have to update that other module.

Comment: @jfriend00 thank you i realized the issue was Formidable is in caps. I ran npm update Formidable and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my comment, it looks like you can fix it with:

```
npm update Formidable
```

to upgrade your formidable module to a more recent version.